# Creating a convertAll() function that converts all .filetype in working directory

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I seem to not know proper bash syntax; despite this, I've tried to create a tool that changes the dimensions of all files of a ffmpeg-accepted filetype in the working directory and converts it to another ffmpeg-accepted filetype. In this instance, this tool converts all .webm files over 1080x720 into 1080x-1 or -1x720 .mp4 files. If the .webm file is under 1080x720, the new .mp4 file will have the same dimensions.

However, there's a wrench in the tool.

```
convertAll () {
local wantedWidth = 1080
local wantedHeight = 720
for i in *.webm; do
local newWidth = $i.width
local newHeight = $i.height
until [$newWidth <= $wantedWidth && $newHeight <= $wantedHeight]; do
if [$videoWidth > $wantedWidth]; then
newHeight = $newWidth*($wantedWidth/$newWidth)
newWidth = $newWidth*($wantedWidth/$newWidth)
fi
if [$videoHeight > $wantedHeight]; then
newWidth = $newWidth*($wantedHeight/$newHeight)
newHeight = $newHeight*($wantedHeight/$newHeight)
fi
done
ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf scale=$newWidth:$newHeight "${i%.*}.mp4";
done
echo "All files have been converted."
}
```

What this returns is a bunch of lines that look like this:

```
bash: [: missing ']'
bash: [: missing ']'
bash: =: No such file or directory
```

My best guess is that BASH can't do mathematics, and that I'm declaring and editing my variables incorrectly.

I'd like some input on this --- my lack of experience is really getting me here.

Comment: Pass your script through www.shellcheck.net. It will tell you the most common errors in your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have a new resource. Have a great day, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most essential part will be to detect the dimention of the input video
and calculate the desired dimension depending on the case.
`ffmpeg` does it for you.
Please try:

```
covertAll() {
    for i in *.webm; do
        ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf "scale='min(1080,iw)':'min(720,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease" "${i%.*}.mp4"
    done
}
```

It will scale the dimensions as follows (examples):

```
1080x720 => 1080x720
1440x720 => 1080x540
720x1080 =>  480x720
720x480  =>  720x480
etc.
```